# Is it OK to make an IAP product free?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am considering making a google play store in-app consumable product 
free for a limited period. I know that this cannot be done within 
the play store. But I could do it within the app.
Is there any policy about this?

Comment: Please check [FAQs on Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and make it  [**Minimal**, Complete and Verfiable Example(MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well I did it with any complaint. So I guess it is.